# Toolbar missing in the child activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-toolbar

I'm trying to create a simple Android app, which holds a user-defined list. The main activity will display some contents associated with the list, and a separate activity will be used to let the user manage the contents of the list.

`MainActivity` sets up the `Toolbar` and starts the auxilliary activity:

`MainActivity.kt`:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val toolbar by lazy { findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar) }
    private val drawerLayout by lazy { findViewById<DrawerLayout>(R.id.drawerLayout) }
    // This button is defined somewhere deep in `activity_main.xml`
    private val manageLocationsButton by lazy { findViewById<Button>(R.id.manage_locations) }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Connect the action bar and the navigation drawer
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

        val toggle =
                ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                        this,
                        drawerLayout,
                        toolbar,
                        R.string.drawerOpen,
                        R.string.drawerClose
                )
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
        toggle.syncState()

        manageLocationsButton.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, ManageLocationsActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

`activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white" />

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- contents -->
    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The auxilliary activity doesn't do anything in particular:
`ManageLocationsActivity.kt`:

```
class ManageLocationsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_manage_locations)

        // The code below will crash, as supportActionBar == null
        // supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    }
}
```

I'd expect the child activity to inherit the toolbar, but it doesn't happen. There is no toolbar whatsoever in the child activity, when it's started.
My app is using `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`, which is necessary to use a `Toolbar` as opposed to `ActionBar` (which is the modern way AFAIK)

How can I make child activities inherit the action bar and use the default back navigation?

Answer (score 2):

This approach you use works if you have only one activity and multiple fragments. But if you have multiple activities like you do, you must have toolbar in all of your activities's layouts.
If you have multiple activities and do not want to copy and paste your toolbar to all of them, just create seperate layout for only toolbar and include it to the layouts you want tollbar to show to.

```
<include layout="@layout/your_toolbar_layout" />
```

Comment: For completeness, can you link to some reference on how to use Fragments for what I'm doing instead?

Comment: Sure, i suggest you to use single activity and as many as fragment you want. This Philipp guy is a good teacher and in this video for the beginners [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-vAI7RSPxOA) For the navigation between fragments, the best approach is to use navigation components and this video from Stevdza-San teaching that [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DI0NIk-7cz8)